# Two values in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I attempted this list comprehension:

```
[sqrt(x), x**2 for x in range(rng)]
```

but apparently this syntax doesn't work. I suppose I could do something like this:

```
[fn(x), fn(x) for x in range(rng) for fn in (sqrt(), lambda x: x**2)]
```

but is there no cleaner way?

Edit: let's say `rng` is 3. I'd want an output of `[0, 0, 1, 1, √2, 4]`

Comment: Can you clarify what result you want?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem specification.  Touch the MCVE checkpoints, please: post both expected and actual results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

```
[fx for x in range(rng) for fx in [sqrt(x), x**2]]
```

or:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([sqrt(x), x**2] for x in range(rng)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double for-loop:

```
from math import sqrt
rng = 3
print([item for x in range(rng) for item in (sqrt(x), x**2)])
# [0.0, 0, 1.0, 1, 1.4142135623730951, 4]
```